# How can I order Nginx to stop redirect to its 404 page?

Tags: nginx

I have a website made by .net core ran in windows IIS before.

Now I modify it to centos and run by Nginx.

I code in the back-end to redirect different 404 pages for different language users and all runs well in IIS.

Meanwhile, now in Nginx, it will only redirect to the default 404 pages of Nginx.

I searched for this problem in Google, someone said that there must be an`error_page 404` property which set the 404 page in the `nginx.conf`

However, this property does not exist in my `nginx.conf`

How can I stop Nginx from doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`error_page 404` is usually located at 
`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

If it is not there by default, you can check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04) post. It covers custom 404 pages.

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: I am afraid not. I want the 404 page control by the back-end only but not control by the Nginx.